# Python Loop is running over range

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to append 50,000 photo numpy arrays to a list.  However, this is going over the 50,000 range.  Do I have the loop in the wrong place?

Code below:

```
X = []
y = []


for i in range(50000):
    n = 0
    for features, label in training_data:
        X.append(features)
        y.append(label)
        n += 1
        print(n)
```

Comment: You're looping over `training_data` 50000 times. So you'll loop `50_000 * len(training_data)` times

Comment: Note: Instead of using a counter ```n``` you can use ```enumerate```

Comment: your `n` will print the amount of data in `training_data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive this is what you're looking for:

```
X = []
y = []

for features, label in training_data[:50000]:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)
```

This will take the first 50000 elements of the `training_data`, and append their `features` and `label`s to `X` and `y` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the outer `for` loop. You're running 50000^2 times because you nested the loops. The first loop tells the program to run 50000 times, but once you enter the second loop, it goes through the entire numpy array, adds everything, and then increments `i` by one and adds everything again. So, with this code, you're actually going to add each item in your array to a new list 50000 times.